# Merge Sort Not Working?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I'm having some trouble getting my Merge Sort function to work with the specifications given to me by my professor. Been staring at VS and Google for an eternity trying to figure this guy out.

The algorithm provided:

[image]

arrayFunctions.h

```
template<class T>
void printArray(T arr[], int numElements)
{
    cout << "(";

    for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++)
    {

        cout << arr[i];

        if (i < numElements - 1)
            cout << ", ";
    }

    cout << ")" << "\n\n";
}

template <class T>
void setArray(T to[], T from[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        to[i] = from[i];
}

template <class T>
void setArray(T to[], T from[], int size1, int size2)
{
    int size = size1;
    if (size2 < size1) size = size2;

    setArray(to, from, size);
}
```

main

```
const int NUM = 5;

int originalArray[NUM] = { 4, 2, 5, 3, 1 };
int newArray[NUM];

cout << "Original:\n";
printArray(originalArray, NUM); //prints an array with formatting

// Merge Sort
setArray(newArray, originalArray, NUM); //set's newArray to the same values of originalArray
mergeSort(newArray, 0, NUM - 1);

cout << "Merge Sort:\n";
printArray(newArray, NUM);

pause();
```

The output when running main is:

Original:
(4, 2, 5, 3, 1 )

Merge Sort:
(0, 0, 0, -33686019, 1)

merge:

```
template <class T>
void merge(T L[], int lowerBound, int mid, int upperBound)
{
    // Get size for new arrays
    int size1 = mid - lowerBound;
    int size2 = upperBound - mid;

    // Create Temporary Arrays
    T * tmp1 = new T[size1 + 1]();
    T * tmp2 = new T[size2 + 1]();


    // Populate both arrays from original
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
        tmp1[i] = L[lowerBound + i];

    for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++)
        tmp2[j] = L[mid + j];

    tmp1[size1] = numeric_limits<T>::max();
    tmp2[size2] = numeric_limits<T>::max();

    int i = 0;
    int j = i;

    for (int k = lowerBound; k < upperBound; k++)
    {
        if (tmp1[i] <= tmp2[j])
        {
            L[k] = tmp1[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            L[k] = tmp2[j];
            j++;
        }
    }

    delete[] tmp1;
    delete[] tmp2;
}
```

mergeSort:

```
template<class T>
void mergeSort(T L[], int lowerBound, int upperBound)
{
    if (lowerBound < upperBound)
    {
        int mid = (lowerBound + upperBound) / 2;

        mergeSort(L, lowerBound, mid);
        mergeSort(L, mid + 1, upperBound);

        merge(L, lowerBound, mid, upperBound);
    }
}
```

So... what am I doing wrong? A bump in the right direction would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: When you used the debugger, which lines or variables are causing the issue?

Comment: What does `setArray` do?  Have you tested it?  Does it function correctly?

Comment: Voting to close -- no evidence O.P. used a debugger.  I don't want to waste my time trying to get the code to compile and use a debugger on it for the O.P>

Comment: Why is your sentinel `infinity` commented out? Can't you use `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()`? I think that's the issue. As you don't have the sentinel, you're copying the garbage in positions `size1+1` or `size2+1`.

Comment: I'm not getting any compile or fatal run time errors, so I'm not sure.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I commented out what set array does. It just loops through a given array and puts it's values in a new one. Also, I'm in the debugger right now :p

And yes, setArray does work. I've used it with my other sorting functions and have had no issues.

Comment: @Yamaneko  I commented out infinity because I don't know what it's supposed to do. It's in the code given to me, so I left it there as a reference.

Comment: Sorry, but since the `setArray` function is not in the code you presented, I can't recreate your program.  Since I cannot recreate your program, I cannot use a debugger for you.

Comment: @Gurman8r `infinity` being commented out is one of the issues. It is used as a sentinel, so when you reach the last position of `tmp1` (or `tmp2`), it'll ensure that you copy all the other elements from the other array, `tmp2` (or `tmp1`). You can represent `inf` here using `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()`.

Also, consider @ThomasMatthews advice, and include the code remaining. It may be hiding other sources of issues.

Comment: Added in the other functions. Going to try what @Yamaneko said.

Comment: @Gurman8r I'm assuming here that the type `T` is an `int`, `float`, or `double`.

Comment: Code seems to be working (sort of). It returns the correct values, but only with the first two sorted. (2, 4, 5, 3, 1)

Comment: @Gurman8r - I found a fix that seems to work and posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for forgetting to reply for nearly two weeks :/

It was a few off by one errors, but I tracked them down and got it working.
Thanks to everyone who helped.

Changed

```
int size1 = mid - lowerBound;
int size2 = upperBound - mid;
```

to

```
int size1 = mid - lowerBound + 1;
int size2 = upperBound - mid;
```

Changed

```
for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++)
    tmp2[j] = L[mid + j];
```

to

```
for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++)
    tmp2[j] = L[mid + j + 1];
```

Changed

```
for (int k = lowerBound; k < upperBound; k++)
{
    if (tmp1[i] <= tmp2[j])
    {
        L[k] = tmp1[i];
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        L[k] = tmp2[j];
        j++;
    }
}
```

to

```
for (int k = lowerBound; k <= upperBound; k++)
{
    if (tmp1[i] <= tmp2[j])
    {
        L[k] = tmp1[i];
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        L[k] = tmp2[j];
        j++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a simple off by one error.

```
T * tmp1 = new T[size1 + 1]();
...
tmp1[size1 + 1] = numeric_limits<T>::max();
           ^^^
```

Array indexes go from `0` to `n-1`, not to `n`.

Comment: Thanks, just caught that.

Comment: oh come on, nothing to say about raw `new`? :)

Comment: @TemplateRex it's obvious this is homework, and learning how to deal with raw pointers is useful even if you never use it again.

Answer (score 2):

```
// tmp1[size1 + 1] = (infinity?)
// tmp2[size2 + 1] = (infinity?)
```

This is the part of the code that is breaking your merge, think about what would happen if you have two lists with 1 more element in them then they should, see:

```
// Create Temporary Arrays
T * tmp1 = new T[size1 + 1]();
T * tmp2 = new T[size2 + 1]();
```

That means that they could look something like this for 2 values

```
foo = [1,2,?]
bar = [3,4,?]
```

the questionmark will be some number but you have no way of knowing what, if you then run the comparison inside the loop a few times you will get to lets say **i = 2, j == 0** for simplicity, now you try to do the comparison:

```
if (foo[2] <= bar[0])
```

and that's the same as

```
if (? <= 3)
```

meaning you have a undefined behavior, and what gets even worse is that you might go to **i = 3** and start looking at random memory.
So in conclusion, **(infinity?)** in some smart way.

Comment: "in conclusion, (infinity?) in some smart way" - probably that's what the lines assigning `numeric_limits<T>::max()` are trying to do, though.

Comment: @davmac that's because he changed the question. Before I suggested `numeric_limits<T>::max()`, it was `(infinity?)` and the lines were commented out.

Comment: @davmac Yes, but as this looks like a school assignment I figured that giving away the correct answer might be unproductive. ;)

Comment: @davmac No problem! :) I explained because I actually think that he shouldn't have changed it, as it was part of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In the C++ merge function, the right half of L[] starts with mid + 1, so the second populate loop should be:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++)
        tmp2[j] = L[mid + j + 1];
```

In the provided algorithm, indices go from 1 to n, so the first populate loop is TMP1[i] ← L[lowerBound + i - 1]. With C++, indices go from 0 to n-1, so the C++ first populate loop: tmp1[i] = L[lowerBound + i]; is correct, but the second loop needs to be changed to tmp2[j] = L[mid + j + 1]; .

Answer (score 0):

### Issue 1: Sentinels

`infinity` being commented out is one of the issues.

```
// tmp1[size1] = (infinity?)
// tmp2[size2] = (infinity?)
```

It is used as a sentinel, so when you reach the last position of `tmp1` (or `tmp2`), it'll ensure that you copy all the other elements from the other array, `tmp2` (or `tmp1`). You can represent `inf` here using `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()`.

@Petter made a good description of why this issue happens.

### Issue 2: Initialization

Your other issue seems to be in the initialization, before merging your arrays:

```
int i = 1;
int j = i;
```

The pseudo-code is indexing from `1`, while it should start from `0`.

### Issue 3: Indexing

As pointed out by @MarkRansom, the indexing range should be from `0` to `size1`, instead of `size1 + 1`.

```
tmp1[size1 + 1] = numeric_limits<T>::max();
```